# Error when Integrating a Sinatra App into a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sinatra

This [article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-share-a-session-between-sinatra-and-rails) describes an easy way to share sessions between a Sinatra app and a Rails app in routes.rb:

```
MyRailsApp::Application.routes.draw do
  mount MySinatraApp.new => '/api'
end
```

To create my Sinatra app, I followed this [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-websockets) which describes how to create a Sinatra WebSockets example.

Similar to the method above, this is what I tried in routes.rb:

```
MyRailsApp::Application.routes.draw do
  mount ChatDemo::ChatBackend.new => '/api'
end
```

But I see this error:

```
! Unable to load application: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
/sinatra_rails_test2/config/application.rb:22:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
```

It looks like the app has to be passed in as an argument.  How would I do that in the routes.rb file?  Is that the right solution?

For reference, this is what the initialize method looks like in /lib/chat_app.rb:

```
require 'faye/websocket'
require 'thread'
require 'redis'
require 'json'
require 'erb'

module ChatDemo
  class ChatBackend
    KEEPALIVE_TIME = 15 # in seconds
    CHANNEL        = "chat-demo"

    def initialize(app)
      @app     = app
      @clients = []
      uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"])
      @redis = Redis.new(host: uri.host, port: uri.port, password: uri.password)
      Thread.new do
        redis_sub = Redis.new(host: uri.host, port: uri.port, password: uri.password)
        redis_sub.subscribe(CHANNEL) do |on|
          on.message do |channel, msg|
            @clients.each {|ws| ws.send(msg) }
          end
        end
      end
    end

    # the module continues...
```

Comment: "mount ChatApp.new => '/api'" actually worked once I commented out "module ChatDemo".